# C#: Inherited class with methods taking Child type as a parameter: wrong method being called

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

*EDIT:* This question does not reflect my exact situation, so I have posted a much more relevant question here: [Inherited class with methods taking Child type as a parameter: wrong method being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768952/unity3d-c-inherited-class-with-methods-taking-child-type-as-a-parameter-wrong)

I have a bit of an issue that I am having a bit of trouble getting my head around.

I have a parent class of type BaseClass, which has a method that takes a BaseClass parameter:

```
public void copyAttributes(BaseClass bc){
 //Copy the attributes from bc to this class
}
```

I also have a inherited type called ChildClass which has a method of the same name that takes a parameter of type ChildClass.

```
public void copyAttributes(ChildClass cc){
 //Copy the attributes from cc to this class
}
```

I am using generics in a method that calls the method:

```
public void Foo<T>(...,T objectToCopy, ...) where T : BaseClass{
 ChildClass thisObject = new ChildClass();
 thisObject.copyAttributes(..., objectToCopy, ...);
 Console.writeline(thisObject.printAllAttributes());
}
```

However, if I call it like this:

```
Foo<ChildClass>(..., new ChildClass(...), ...);
```

it runs the parent class's method, not the child class's method, so the attributes specific to the child class do not get set.

I don't understand this, I'm passing in something that is specifically the ChildClass type, why does it decide to use the BaseClass type instead?

Why is this, and how can I work around this?

Comment: How is the compiler letting you run the code in the first place? `thisObject.copyAttributes(objectToCopy)` should give a compilation error considering `objectToCopy` is of type T

Comment: Are you missing a `where T : BaseClass` constraint on `Foo`? This shouldn't compile at all. Assuming you are, this is because the call to `copyAttributes` is resolved statically inside `Foo` and the base class method will be the only suitable candidate.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to mention that. Yes I did, I'll update the question.

Comment: @Lee How can I force it to resolve to the child class?

Comment: Posted a link to my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768952/unity3d-c-inherited-class-with-methods-taking-child-type-as-a-parameter-wrong. This question is too simplified for me to get the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to fully comprehend your question without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Making some inferences, I am going to guess that an appropriate code example would actually look like this:

```
class A
{
    public void M(A a) { Console.WriteLine("A.M"); }
}

class B : A
{
    public void M(B a) { Console.WriteLine("B.M"); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();

        M(b);
    }

    static void M<T>(T t) where T : A
    {
        B b = new B();

        b.M(t);
    }
}
```

In particular, note the constraint on the generic method `void M<T>(T t) where T : A`. This would be required in order to even be able to compile the code.

Now, as far as the behavior you're seeing: it's important to keep in mind that overload resolution is something that happens at compile time. The compiler has to pick, based on the information available to it at the time, which method to call.

In your generic method, all that you've told it is that the parameter `t` must be of type `A`. It might be a *more derived* type, but all that the compiler can count on is that it's an `A`. As such, it has to pick the overload that it knows for sure will be valid; i.e. the method in `A`.

So, what to do about it?

Well, the easiest fix would be to make the calling method dynamic instead of generic:

```
    static void M(dynamic t)
    {
        B b = new B();

        b.M(t);
    }
```

In doing so, you force the compilation step of overload resolution to take place at run-time instead of compile-time. And of course at run-time the compiler knows what type to use.

Note though that this does involve essentially compiling that section of code at run-time, which is extra overhead. If you can change the declarations of the class somewhat, you can use polymorphism to have the same effect:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void M(A a) { Console.WriteLine("A.M"); }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void M(A a) { Console.WriteLine("B.M"); }
}
```

Of course, `B.M(A)` can cast the argument `a` to type `B` for the purpose of accessing the members in `B` (the caller would of course be required to ensure it passes an object of the appropriate type), and `B.M(A)` can even call the base class implementation (i.e. as `base.M(a);` so that it doesn't have to duplicate effort.

I hope that the above explains the problem well enough and offers useful workarounds. Unfortunately, without a better code example, it's hard to really understand how you got into the situation (for one, the generic method doesn't seem generic in any useful way, at least as shown in the example).

Comment: I cut my code down to extreme basics, I am starting to think I overdid it. This is a Unity3D project with some strange requirements for generics, so I have work around certain things.

Comment: I'm going to post a new question and link it here since the scope is changed.

Comment: This does solve the issue, I went with the virtual option.