# Inherited class with methods taking Child type as a parameter: wrong method being called

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, polymorphism

I am making a card game, and I have several scripts that control card behavior.

```
public class BasicCardModel : Draggable {
    public int hitPoints;
    public GameObject cardObject;
    public static string cardName = "Basic Card";

    public CardStatus cardStatus = CardStatus.None;

    public void copyAttributes(BasicCardModel bcm) {
        Debug.Log("Calling basic copy attributes");
        hitPoints = bcm.hitPoints;
    }
    ...
}
```

I have several specialized cards similar to below:

```
public class AttackCardModel : BasicCardModel {
    public int attackStrength;
    public AttackType attackType;

    public void copyAttributes(AttackCardModel acm) {
        base.copyAttributes(acm);
        attackType = acm.attackType;
        Debug.Log("Attack strength = " + acm.attackStrength);
        attackStrength = acm.attackStrength;
    }
}
```

I have a controller object that generates these cards:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject basicCard, attackCard, defenseCard, eventCard, masterCard;
    public GameObject topPlayerDeck, topPlayerHand, topPlayerField;
    public GameObject bottomPlayerDeck, bottomPlayerHand, bottomPlayerField;
    public GameObject eventDeck;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Link controller to game objects
        topPlayerDeck = GameObject.Find("TopPlayerDeck");
        topPlayerHand = GameObject.Find("TopPlayerHand");
        topPlayerField = GameObject.Find("TopPlayerField");
        bottomPlayerDeck = GameObject.Find("BottomPlayerDeck");
        bottomPlayerHand = GameObject.Find("BottomPlayerHand");
        bottomPlayerField = GameObject.Find("BottomPlayerField");
        eventDeck = GameObject.Find("EventDeck");

        CardCollection cards = generateCards();

        foreach (BasicCardModel card in cards.cards) {
            if(card is AttackCardModel) {
                createCard<AttackCardModel>(topPlayerHand, card as AttackCardModel, Player.Top, CardStatus.Hand);
                createCard<AttackCardModel>(bottomPlayerHand, card as AttackCardModel, Player.Bottom, CardStatus.Hand);
            }
            else if(card is DefenseCardModel) {
                createCard<DefenseCardModel>(topPlayerHand, card as DefenseCardModel, Player.Top, CardStatus.Hand);
                createCard<DefenseCardModel>(bottomPlayerHand, card as DefenseCardModel, Player.Bottom, CardStatus.Hand);
            }
            else {
                createCard<BasicCardModel>(topPlayerHand, card as BasicCardModel, Player.Top, CardStatus.Hand);
                createCard<BasicCardModel>(bottomPlayerHand, card as BasicCardModel, Player.Bottom, CardStatus.Hand);
            }
        }

        /*
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            createCard<AttackCardModel>(topPlayerHand, Player.Top, CardStatus.Hand);
            createCard<AttackCardModel>(bottomPlayerHand, Player.Bottom, CardStatus.Hand);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            createCard<DefenseCardModel>(topPlayerHand, Player.Top, CardStatus.Hand);
            createCard<DefenseCardModel>(bottomPlayerHand, Player.Bottom, CardStatus.Hand);
        }
        */
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    // For testing, have a CardCollection passed in later
    public CardCollection generateCards() {
        CardCollection cards = new CardCollection();
        //AttackCardModel testcard = new AttackCardModel(4, AttackType.SQLInjection, 3);
        cards.cards.Add(new AttackCardModel(4, AttackType.SQLInjection, 3));
        cards.cards.Add(new DefenseCardModel(5, AttackType.SQLInjection, 1));
        //Debug.Log(testcard.attackStrength + "is attack strength");
        return cards;
    }

    public void createCard<T>(GameObject whereToPut, T objectToCopy, Player player, CardStatus cardStatus) where T : BasicCardModel {
        GameObject new_card = Instantiate(basicCard);
        new_card.transform.SetParent(whereToPut.transform, false);
        Destroy(new_card.GetComponent<BasicCardModel>());
        new_card.AddComponent<T>();
        --->new_card.GetComponent<T>().copyAttributes(objectToCopy); <---
        new_card.GetComponent<T>().linkModelToCardObject(new_card);
        new_card.GetComponent<T>().setUpCard<T>(player, cardStatus);
    }
}
```

I am having trouble with this line (near the end of the controller object):
`new_card.GetComponent<T>().copyAttributes(objectToCopy);`

Instead of calling the child method for `copyAttributes`, it calls the parent method, and thus does not copy the attributes that I want.

In my previous question about this, one person suggested using dynamic typing as a solution. However, even though `GetComponent<ParentClass>` should get the child types, it doesn't work for some reason, so I need to use generics.

How can I force it to call the child method instead of the parent method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `BasicCardModel`'s `copyAttributes` method virtual.

```
public class BasicCardModel : Draggable {
    // ...    
    public virtual void copyAttributes(BasicCardModel bcm) {
        // ...    
    }
    // ...    
}
```

Then override it `AttackCardModel`, and cast the card model to the derived type before copying additional attributes:

```
public override void copyAttributes(BasicCardModel bcm) {
    base.copyAttributes(acm);
    var acm = bcm as AttackCardModel;
    if (acm != null) {
        attackType = acm.attackType;
        Debug.Log("Attack strength = " + acm.attackStrength);
        attackStrength = acm.attackStrength;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah!! That's clever. Any reason for using `var` or is it just convenience?

Comment: @ChrisChambers: note that this is exactly one of the options I provided in my answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768384/c-inherited-class-with-methods-taking-child-type-as-a-parameter-wrong-method). I'd say that the simplified example was sufficient to get your question answered after all.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Huh, I guess I didn't look closely enough. The reason I didn't see it was my own fault, I needed to see it in the environment I'm working with.

Comment: Using `var` for declaring local variable is optional. In this case it's clear what type it must be as the statement spells out the type in the cast. When you are assigning the result of a method call it can be less obvious at first glance. Despite this, many style guides recommend always using `var`. Your IDE should help you check the type if you are not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reflect the hierarchy in your types - one way is to create an interface and add a constraint for it in your `Create` method:

```
public interface ICopyableFrom<T>
{
     void CopyAttributes(T src);
}

public void createCard<T>(GameObject whereToPut, T objectToCopy, Player player, CardStatus cardStatus) where T : BasicCardModel, ICopyableFrom<T>
{
        GameObject new_card = Instantiate(basicCard);
        new_card.transform.SetParent(whereToPut.transform, false);
        Destroy(new_card.GetComponent<BasicCardModel>());
        new_card.AddComponent<T>();
        new_card.GetComponent<T>().CopyAttributes(objectToCopy);
        new_card.GetComponent<T>().linkModelToCardObject(new_card);
        new_card.GetComponent<T>().setUpCard<T>(player, cardStatus);
}
```

which you then need to implement in your classes:

```
public class AttackCardModel : BasicCardModel, ICopyableFrom<AttackCardModel>
{
    public void CopyAttributes(AttackCardModel src)
    {
    }
}
```